Replace a series of the same character by its number of occurrences in the series
I get a string like this:
AABBBB$CCCDEEE$AABADEE

And I want a result like this:
2A4B$3CD3E$2ABAD2E

To do that, I made a for loop on the string array.
It works well:
import re

string = "AABBBB$CCCDEEE$AABADEE"
out_string = string[:]
k = 1
c_old = ""
for c in string:
    if c_old==c :
        k += 1
    else:
        if k>1:
            s= ""
            for i in range(k):
                s += c_old
            chg = str(k) + c_old
            out_string = re.sub(s, chg, out_string, 1)
        k = 1
    c_old = c

print(out_string)

But with very long strings, it can take a long time.
Is there a way to do what I want without iterating all the string, especially with the re module?

Just read the characters one by one and build the output like you would do by hand? Why would you try this overcomplicated thing with re.sub?

Is there a reason you are doing this with regular expressions? I ask because your current code will fail with some strings like "C++D". It's not clear from your question if you are trying do something unusual or just trying to do run-length-encoding.

You can try using a regex to solve this. What have you tried?

@Wiktor Stribiżew : I tried but I didn't find a solid/robust regex that works at all

Your encoding scheme is ambiguous. For example, if the input string is "2X", your scheme would output "2X". But that can be decoded as either "2X" or "XX", so the encoding isn't guaranteed to round-trip. To work properly, the encoding should include all run-lengths (i.e. "2X" => "121X").

How would something like re.sub(r'(.)\1+', lambda m: str(len(m[0])) + m[1], s) compare to your current function?

Ok my loop isn't good. I got a better one on my next message. And @SIGHUP had very nice one. But I was thinking about 2 steps : extract the series and then replace the series. I hoped that 2 regex 'substitution' wil work.

On shorter strings @SIGHUP's solution looks to be considerable faster. The longer the string gets, this one getes closer... see benchmark (perfpy).

Not sure why you think re.sub() is appropriate for this. You just need a fairly trivial iteration over the source string.
Something like this:
s = "AABBBB$CCCDEEE$AABADEE"

r = ""
c = 1
p = s[0]

for x in s[1:]:
    if x == p:
        c += 1
    else:
        if c == 1:
            r += p
        else:
            r += f"{c}{p}"
            c = 1
        p = x
else:
    r += p if c == 1 else f"{c}{p}"

print(r)

Output:
2A4B$3CD3E$2ABAD2E


As an R user I am always surprised that Python does not have a run length encoding built-in and I frequently use python-rle.
import rle
string = 'AABBBB$CCCDEEE$AABADEE'

''.join(
    f"{num}{letter}" if num > 1 else letter 
     for letter, num in zip(*rle.encode(string))
)

# '2A4B$3CD3E$2ABAD2E'


I think the best answer I search is given by @bobble bubble
re.sub(r'(.)\1+', lambda m: str(len(m[0])) + m[1], s)

in a comment on 1rst message.

@SIGHUP : Yes you're alright. I've tested with a long string (4704 characters) the 2 methods. Regex method takes real=0.920s, user=0.112s, sys=0.063s.  The For Loop method takes real=0.216s, user=0.077s, sys=0.026s.

Answer to the comments.
Perhaps something like that :
string = "AABBBB$CCCDEEE$AABADEE"
out_string = ""
k = 1
c_old = ""
for c in string + " ":
    if c_old==c :
        k += 1
    else:
        if k>1:
            out_string = out_string + str(k)
        out_string = out_string + c_old
        k = 1
     c_old = c

print(out_string)

